# Group sales by the person who made them and time they were made. Rails and Postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, date, time

In my rails application, I have a products table and a sales table. 
Each sales entry has a product and an amount, so each time a sale is made, more than one entry to the sales table happens because clients usually buy more than one product. 
I now need a way to group all the sales entries made by the same client (the table has an associated client_id) at the same time (using the created_at column) into one big sale and pass them to an array so that I can display them.

How can I do this?

Comment: please provide sample table data and desired output ? however you can achieved this using joins query.but you need to rethink your db architecture.please do normalization on database.

Comment: I know my db architecture isn't great but I can't think of any other way to do it. How can I add more than one product to a sale? Is there a way to improve this? On the sales table my columns are: quantity, product_id, client_id, employee_id (to record what employee made the sale), and the default id, created_at and updated_at fields. But the thing is, when clients buy something, they are going to have more than one product with different quantities.

Comment: which column you are using as primary key ?

Comment: The default id column is the primary key and product_id, client_id and employee_id are foreign keys.

Comment: what i will do is add extra column to sales table as orderid and whenever customer is start purchasing products i create a unique orderid for his current session programmatically and insert different products with any no of quantity associated with same orderid.

Comment: generally the better approach is having tables such as customer(cid),order(oid(p.k),cid(f.k)),products(pid(p.k)),order_products(pid(f.k),oid(f.k))

Comment: YES!!!! That makes so much sense!!! But how can I programatically insert different products with the same order id???

Comment: Could you help me with the code for that?? Im fairly new at this.

Comment: tell me what issue you are facing currently while inserting to sales ?

Comment: I just need to know how to programatically insert values into the sales table with the same order id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I suggest a little tweak on your current approach?

Add an orders model that groups these sales together because it makes more sense and it's a lot more "rails way" than trying to group by created_at date which might cause some bugs down the line. Here's what I suggest:

**order**

```
id
user_id

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**sales**

```
id
order_id
product_id

class Sales < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :order
end
```

**user**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
end
```

This way, when you want to display all the sales grouped by the order (instead or created_at) you'll be able to loop over `@user.orders`

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! But I still have one question, how is the order model grouping the sales together? What columns will the order model have?

Comment: You're welcome. There are a few ways. One you can create the order and add the sales individually like @order.sales.new(sales_params). You can also use nested attributes. You can refer here http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1